# Suddenly element of the vector became uninitialized

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I have next program part and can't undestand what is hell going wrong there. I generate some Entity object, i see that it is good and fully initialized, then i push this object into the empty vector _goodPopulation and see that for sure _goodPopulation[0] is same way initialized, but after program control returns to other method in that class  _goodPopulation[0] suddenly became uninitialized... Why?

//.h

```
std::vector<Entity*> _goodPopulation;
...
```

//.cpp

```
bool ChallengeManager::SelectGoodEnteties(double targetEffectivity)
{
    for (...)
    {
        Entity& ent = _entityGenerator->GenerateEntity();
        if (ent.GetEffectiveness() > 0) {
            _goodPopulation.push_back(&Entity(ent)); //coping Entity that was generated 
            Entity* ent2 = _goodPopulation[0];//  Just for debugging - Entity object is correct there and fully initialized
            if (ent.GetEffectiveness() > targetEffectivity) 
            { 
                return true; 
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

Entity* ChallengeManager::AchiveEffectivity(double targetEffectivity)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (SelectGoodEnteties(targetEffectivity)) {
            Entity* ent2 = _goodPopulation[0]; // Here _goodPopulation[0] Entity suddenly became uninitialized, all it fields are random numbers
            return _goodPopulation[_goodPopulation.size() - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using multithreading?

Comment: @rockstartprogrammer. Not, program is very simple

Comment: I'm curious about the `_entityGenerator->GenerateEntity()` call, could you perhaps show the `GenerateEntity` function too?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg than i will need to show couple more methods.. GenerateEntity() do the next thing: it reset content of Entity by setting it fields to zero(i am reusing the single entity for generation, to not have perfomance overhed, and copy only good enteties), and random generating it elements

Comment: What I'm wondering is if it returns a reference to a local or temporary variable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i have singleton object _entity that lives for ever. It returns reference on this object, i feel it in the GenerateEntity(), then if object was good - by my plan coping it to vectory(here as i see is mistake), then reset, and feel agein...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_goodPopulation.push_back(&Entity(ent));
```

On this line you create a local variable Entity(ent) on a stack and get its address. Once you go out of scope that local variable is destroyed and address is not valid anymore.

So you should create a new object in a heap

```
_goodPopulation.push_back(new Entity(ent));
```

Do not forget to delete objects in the vector when you do not need them anymore.

```
for (std::vector<Entity*>::iterator it = _goodPopulation.begin(); it != _goodPopulation.end(); ++it)
    delete *it;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are storing pointers in your vector, and you are pushing the address of a temporary here:

```
_goodPopulation.push_back(&Entity(ent));
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ Temporary Entity object
```

The object pointed to ceases to exist immediately, leaving you with a dangling pointer. De-referencing it is *undefined behaviour*. Whatever you push has to point to an object that lives long enough to be de-referenced.

It *could* be that you meant

```
_goodPopulation.push_back(&ent);
```

which would work if the reference returned by `_entityGenerator->GenerateEntity();` is valid for long enough.

Comment: +1: So golden rule is never put address in vector (any container)?

Comment: @rockstartprogrammer I would say it depends. Sometimes you really do need a non-owning container of pointers. You just have to be sure the pointees outlive the container (or at least any attempt to de-reference the contents.)

Comment: @uanchopanza Thank you! But _goodPopulation.push_back(&ent) is not that i mean, i have singleton _entity that i am reusing to not create object each time, and that why here i want to create new object with copy constructor

Comment: @BransDs then do you really need to store pointers? It would be easier to use `std::vector<Entity>`, unless you are using `Entity` polymorphically. A vector of newed pointers is quite a fragile construct.

Comment: @juanchopanza Because at the end i will use custom selection algorithm to chose top N enteties according it effectivness, and coping of pointers, i think will be faster then coping of raw objects.

Comment: @BransDs You should profile that and see. It may be right, in which case you should use `unique_ptr`, or a dynamic object container which takes care of memory management (see the  `boost::pointer_container` library).

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, thank you, but not all so easy. I am planing to port this also on CUDA witch doesn't like BOOST and c++11